# Linker error compiling an executable which uses Boost.Thread linking to a static library using Boost.Thread

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, cmake

I have a static library called `MyAwesomeLib`. It is built with the CMakeLists.txt below

```
PROJECT(MyAwesomeLib)

find_package(OpenCV)
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL)
find_package(GLUT)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS thread)

if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
message(SEND_ERROR "Cannot find Boost Thread")
endif(NOT Boost_FOUND)

link_directories (${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR})

INCLUDE(${VTK_USE_FILE})

file(GLOB SRCS "*.cpp" "*.c")
file(GLOB HDRS "*.h")
add_library(MyAwesomeLib STATIC ${SRCS} ${HDRS})
target_link_libraries(MyAwesomeLib ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY})
```

Now I want to build `MyAwesomeExecutable` which needs symbols from `MyAwesomeLib`. Both the executable and the library uses Boost.Thread (thread_group and thread class).

```
PROJECT(MyAwesomeExecutable)

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(VTK REQUIRED)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS thread)

if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
message(SEND_ERROR "Cannot find Boost Thread")
endif(NOT Boost_FOUND)

link_directories (${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR})

INCLUDE(${VTK_USE_FILE})

FILE(GLOB SRCS "*.cpp" "*.c")
FILE(GLOB HDRS "*.h")

ADD_EXECUTABLE(MyAwesomeExecutable ${SRCS} ${HDRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MyAwesomeExecutable MyAwesomeLib ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

When I build `MyAwesomeExecutable`, Visual Studio 2010 build its dependency `MyAwesomeLib` automatically. `MyAwesomeLib` builds just fine. But building `MyAwesomeExecutable` gives the following linker errors:

```
2>MyAwesomeExecutable.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl boost::thread::join(void)" (?join@thread@boost@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl boost::thread_group::join_all(void)" (?join_all@thread_group@boost@@QEAAXXZ)
2>MyAwesomeLib.lib(Face.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl boost::thread::join(void)" (?join@thread@boost@@QEAAXXZ)
2>MyAwesomeExecutable.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl boost::thread::~thread(void)" (??1thread@boost@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: void * __cdecl boost::thread::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_Gthread@boost@@QEAAPEAXI@Z)
2>MyAwesomeLib.lib(Face.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl boost::thread::~thread(void)" (??1thread@boost@@QEAA@XZ)
2>MyAwesomeExecutable.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl boost::thread::start_thread(void)" (?start_thread@thread@boost@@AEAAXXZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl boost::thread::thread<class boost::_bi::bind_t<void,void (__cdecl*)(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >),class boost::_bi::list1<class boost::_bi::value<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > >(class boost::_bi::bind_t<void,void (__cdecl*)(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >),class boost::_bi::list1<class boost::_bi::value<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > >,struct boost::thread::dummy *)" (??$?0V?$bind_t@XP6AXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@ZV?$list1@V?$value@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@_bi@boost@@@_bi@boost@@@_bi@boost@@@thread@boost@@QEAA@V?$bind_t@XP6AXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@ZV?$list1@V?$value@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@_bi@boost@@@_bi@boost@@@_bi@1@PEAUdummy@01@@Z)
2>MyAwesomeLib.lib(Face.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl boost::thread::start_thread(void)" (?start_thread@thread@boost@@AEAAXXZ)
```

Comment: Do you use the auto-linking of Boost? I have had more luck when disabling it: add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB ) and explicitly specify dynamic linking: add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK )

Answer (score 0):

Static library is just a collection of object files. It can compile quite well, because it doesn't use undefined symbols. Several checks can be done to ensure that boost libraries is really linked with your library. Please, do it to provide some more information.

1.Using cmake print out values from `Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS` and `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS`to check linked boost libraries.

2.Check `link.txt` file generated by cmake. This file is generated for each target like library or executable and on Linux it is placed under `buildir/path/to/target/folder/CMakeFiles/targetName.dir/link.txt`. `link.txt` contains compiler command to build and link executable. With it you can check, whether boost thread libraries are actually linked to your executable. In `VS` `link.txt` isn't generated, as said in the comment to this answer. Then you can check for linker command-line using VS itself.

Comment: When building with Visual Studio 10, no link.txt will be generated. That happens with MinGW. Perhaps edit your answer and let him check for the linker command-line in Visual Studio?

Comment: @Andre: Never worked with CMake under VS, so don't know about absence of `link.txt`. Thanks for noticing.